# What command can I use to detect when any player is in a certain area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried using commands from `/testfor @a[r=4.5]`, `/tp @a[r=4.5]`, `/entitydata @e[type=Player,r=4.5]`, etc. and nothing works. I want it to teleport any player within range of my machine. It kind of works as a giant portal but it doesn't work without the teleporting part (duh).

Cons: I can't use `@e` because there's armor stands in the area for other reasons and eventually I'm going to start spawning zombie's in the area for (also) other reasons. I am using 1.10.2 so maybe that's the reason the commands aren't working. Please answer for me and those with similar problems.

Comment: Testfor @p[r=5] for a min range of 5 blocks

Comment: Note - u can use type=Player with @e and it works like @a, u can also use type !=Armo...ur?Stand (i dont know how to spell it :P so it will teleport all entities except armour stands :)

Comment: Whether I do @p, @e or @a, the entity UUID is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use decimal points in selectors. Try something like:

```
/tp @a[r=4] X Y Z
```

Comment: Note that this solution works if the command block is in the center of the area to detect. Use a command such as `/tp @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=4] X Y Z` to test the radius around the block at (0,0,0). (You can also shorten this to  `/tp @a[0,0,0,4] X Y Z`, since `x`, `y`, `z`, and `r` are the default first arguments of a target selector)

Comment: Colorfusion, /tp @a[0,0,0,4] 324 4 -298 didn't even give an output, Are you sure it's 1.10.2 friendly? Also, why is there two spots for typing coordinates?

Comment: @BlueNinja The first set of coordinates is the center of the radius where people will be teleported from. The command you've given will teleport anyone standing within 4 blocks of coordinates (0, 0, 0). If you don't specify coordinates, the radius will be centered around the thing executing the command (like the command block the command is in). You should use the coordinates of your machine for the first set, or leave them blank. The second set is where people are teleported to.